# Unwanted padding bottom in app.css inside Lightning Experience overriding SLDS styling

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, css, lightning-design-system

And now, there's yet another new issue even in Lightning Experience[Desktop].
Here's the screenshot of the same:-
[image: Unwanted padding bottom in app.css inside Lightning Experience overriding SLDS styling]

The above screenshot shows an unwanted padding-bottom of 2.5rem in a class named flexipagePage in the Lightning Experience[Desktop].
Because of this, I'm unable to give full height to my component.

Is it a good practice to override such app.css style taking into account if the Salesforce guys fix that, again the design would break?

It would be great if someone could provide me a good solution for the same.